# Multiple search creteTextFinder app scrip

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a project where I send data to a google sheet through app script.
I need to change the value of some data and used `createTextFinder`.
Thanks to @Mimi in this thread.   But the fact is that I need to replace more than one text.
I need to change the text when the data is appending.
thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
function addUser(sheet) {
  var FILE = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  var sheet = FILE.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var id = "True"; 
  var name = "FALSE";
var t1 = createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES")
var t2 = createTextFinder("FALSE").replaceAllWith("NO")

  sheet.appendRow([id,name]).t1.t2;
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Can you visually clarify your current situation and the expected output? Either a screenshot or a copy of the spreadsheet might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `I need to change the text when the data is appending.`, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var t1 = createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES")
var t2 = createTextFinder("FALSE").replaceAllWith("NO")

  sheet.appendRow([id,name]).t1.t2;
```

#### To:

```
var values = [id, name].map(e => {
  var temp = e.toUpperCase();
  return temp == "TRUE" ? "YES" : temp == "FALSE" ? "NO" : e;
});
sheet.appendRow(values);
```

- For example, when you are required to use TextFinder, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      var t1 = createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES")
      var t2 = createTextFinder("FALSE").replaceAllWith("NO")

        sheet.appendRow([id,name]).t1.t2;
    ```
  - To

    ```
      sheet.appendRow([id, name]);
      sheet.createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES");
      sheet.createTextFinder("FALSE").replaceAllWith("NO");
    ```
  - or, when you want to use TextFinder to the appended row, you can also the following modified script.

    ```
      sheet.appendRow([id, name]);
      // SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might be not required to be used.
      const range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 2);
      range.createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES");
      range.createTextFinder("FALSE").replaceAllWith("NO");
    ```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response @Tanaike. It will change all the data in the sheet. That I was think was, when appending (```sheet.appendRow([id, name]);```) it will replace the text at the same time. Initially the code was ```function  addUser(sheet) {
    var FILE = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXX");
  var sheet = FILE.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var id = "True"; 
  var name = "FALSE" ;
  sheet.appendRow([id,name]).createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES");```

Comment: @P.J Thank you for replying. `TextFinder` can be used for the cell values on the current Spreadsheet. So when you want to use `TextFinder` to `sheet.appendRow([id, name]);`, it is required to use it after `sheet.appendRow([id, name]);` was run. So I proposed 2 patterns in my answer. And, when `sheet.appendRow([id,name]).createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("YES");` is used, `appendRow` returns Class Sheet. By this, all cell values of the sheet is changed. When you want to use it to the appended row, please check my updated script. If my proposed answer was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Multiple Replacement

```
function addUser() {
  const txtA = ['txt1', 'txt2', 'text3'];
  const rplA = ['rpl1', 'rpl2', 'repl3'];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  txtA.forEach((t, i) => {
    let f = sh.createTextFinder(t).findAll();
    if (f) {
      f.forEach(r => { r.setValue(r.getValue().replace(txtA[i], rplA[i])); });
    }
  });
}
```